# Android Close an Fragment Activity and back to the initial display

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I want to make an app that is consists of (1)Main FragmentActivity +(2)Google Map V2 FragmentActivity.

Yet, the following code works successfully show the initial (1)Main FragmentActivity and (2)Google Map V2 FragmentActivity when I click the Button*btn1)..

However, the problem is.. when I click the "Back" button on Android, it successfully kills the 2)Google Map V2 FragmentActivity and show (1)Main FragmentActivity but lost all data on the TextView fields..

so all I want to do is

1. when First click the "back" button, (2)Google Map V2 FragmentActivity should be killed and all data on the TextView fields(at the (1)Main FragmentActivity) should be alive.
2. when Second click the "back" button, the App shuold be killed(exit) with no errors.

thanks

----------MainActivity.java--------------

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    TextView site1_lat, site1_lon, site2_lat, site2_lon, distance_kilo, distance_miles, azimuth1_content, azimuth2_content;
    TextView current_lat, current_lon, current_mgrs_result;
    TextView distance_kilo1, distance_kilo2,    azimuth1_content1, azimuth1_content2;
    Variables vari;

    //for geoCoord
    //Context mContext;
    LocationManager mLocMan;
    String mProvider;
    Location location;
    Context context;
    //double latitude, longitude;
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.recreate();
        //this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview)).commit();
        //this.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        //this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview)).commit();
        //this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview)).commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //for geoCoord
        /*
        mLocMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mProvider = mLocMan.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
        LocationListener mListener = new Geocoord();        
        mLocMan.requestLocationUpdates(mProvider, 6000, 10, mListener);
        */
        //
        mLocMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mProvider = mLocMan.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
        LocationListener mListener = new Geocoord();
        //mLocMan.requestLocationUpdates(mProvider, 0, 0, mListener);
        mLocMan.requestLocationUpdates(mLocMan.GPS_PROVIDER, 6000, 10, mListener);

        /*
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
         */

        //for google Map
        GoogleMap mGoogleMap;


    //Button 0
    final Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //1st site
        try{
        EditText mgrs_site1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String site1 = mgrs_site1.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
        .........

        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please input valid Coordination!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}//ends try-catch      
    }
    }); //ends button0

    //Button 1
    Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btn.performClick();
            //setting up google Map!
            GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
            Converter converter = new Converter();

            //initial values for marker
            //current position
            ...

              setContentView(R.layout.mapview);           
              mGoogleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview)).getMap();
              mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
              //add marker
              mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).title("current")).showInfoWindow();
              mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.site1)).position(position1).title("Site#1")).showInfoWindow();
              mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.site2)).position(position2).title("Site#2")).showInfoWindow();

              //
              mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position1, 7));


            //Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapView.class);
            //startActivity(intent);
        }//ends onClick 



        });

    }//ends onCreate

}//ends Activity

//Things to do
```

Comment: can you add the stack trace for when the app dies?

Comment: You've only shown the `MainActivity`. Where are you starting the other `FragmentActivity`? You can call `finish()` on any `Activity` to remove it from the backstack.

Comment: Thanks Darwind.. but could give me an code example?